# Filter our elements of matrices where both/neither/either are nonzero?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two `numpy` arrays `A`, and `B`. I want to create arrays `Ap` and `Bp` such that `Ap` and `Bp` are all elements of `A` and `B` where at least one of `A` or `B` is nonzero and, alternatively, where neither are zero. An example might be:

```
A = [ 1.1, 0.0, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 0.0, 0.0, 8.1 ]
B = [ 0.0, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 0.0, 0.0, 7.2, 8.2 ]
```

Then in one function I want to generate:

```
Ap = [ 1.1 0.0 3.1 4.1 5.1 0.0 8.1 ]
Bp = [ 0.0 2.2 3.2 4.2 0.0 7.2 8.1 ]
```

and in another I want to geneate:

```
Ap = [ 3.1 4.1 8.1 ]
Bp = [ 3.2 4.2 8.1 ]
```

Right now I am just going through and looking at each element, but I feel like there should be a better/faster way.

Update:

I have a function which calls `(A,B)` and they are `[nx,ny,3]` sized `numpy` arrays. I then call the following:

```
tA = np.copy(A)
tB = np.copy(B)

tA = tA.flatten()
tB = tB.flatten()

Aeq0 = tA==0
Beq0 = tB==0

Ano0 = A!=0
Bno0 = B!=0

As = tA[ Ano0 | Bno0 ]
Bs = tB[ Ano0 | Bno0 ]
```

and it dies at `As = tA[ Ano0 | Bno0 ]`

Answer (score 1):

You use masked indices to achieve that.

```
A = np.asarray(A)
B = np.asarray(B)

ind1 = A!=0
ind2 = B!=0
```

then, to achieve the first case (`|` is an "or" operator):

```
case1 = ind1 | ind2 
Ap = A[case1]
Bp = A[case1]
```

whereas for the second case (`&` is an "and" operator):

```
case2 = ind1 & ind2 
Ap = A[case2]
Bp = A[case2]
```

Comment: Does this change if `A` and `B` start out originally as `n` dimensional `numpy` arrays rather than standard lists? I want `Ap` and `Bp` to be flattened one dimensional arrays that I can pass to pearson correlation functions, but I'm running into errors when I use this method with my data and I wonder if it is because it's not (originally) a list - it's a `n` dimensional tensor.

Comment: @Laurbert515 in that case you could try at the beginning `A = A.flatten()` `B = B.flatten()`, then it should work even for n-dimensional arrays (but the result will obviously be flattened)

Comment: Any chance this would give me `IndexError: too many indices for array` if my data is too big? I tried the `flatten()` method and I got this error. The data is ... not small ;)

Comment: How are you indexing the `flatten` array?  Such array can only take on index (expression), e.g. `a.flatten()[x]`, not `a.flatten()[:,x]`.

Comment: @Laurbert515 you have to build `ind1` and `ind2` **after** you flatten `A` and `B`, this could be a source of such error (not the fact your data is too big)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.T` to create and 2d array of your array columns and use `np.logical_or` within `np.where` :

```
>>> np.array((A,B)).T[np.where(np.logical_or(A,B))[0]]
array([[ 1.1,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  2.2],
       [ 3.1,  3.2],
       [ 4.1,  4.2],
       [ 5.1,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  7.2],
       [ 8.1,  8.2]])
```

And in another case use `np.logical_and` within `np.where`:

```
>>> np.array((A,B)).T[np.where(np.logical_and(A,B))[0]]
array([[ 3.1,  3.2],
       [ 4.1,  4.2],
       [ 8.1,  8.2]])
```